# How to escape \ and other special characters in rust

Tags: rust

I want to using rust to generate a simple tex document, this is my rust code:

```
fn generate_tex(){
    let date = Local::now();
    let timestamp = date.format("%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S").to_string();
    let mut w = File::create("/root/data/learn-word/" + timestamp + ".tex").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "{{ \documentclass[12pt]{book} }}").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "\usepackage{xeCJK}").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "\begin{document}").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "Hello world!  你好").unwrap();
    writeln!(&mut w, "\end{document}").unwrap();
}
```

but the compiler give tips that the `\` was `unknown character escape`, what should I do to make the output was verbate word even if contains special characters? I have tried adding `{{ }}` but it seems it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just `\` (aka `\\` generates an actual `\` character in the output), as it usually is: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#character-escapes

Alternatively, you can use "raw strings", which don't interpret `\` as an escape lead: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals